# Check first 2 Characters in a csv cell using Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Python to script my program and I am reading data from a CSV file.

1. I would like to check for the first 2 characters in each cell under the "Details" column.
2. I would like to filter my data without cells containing "IP" for the first 2 characters.

This is an example of the CSV file:

[image: CSV file]

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far and an example of the input data?

Comment: Refer [How to create Minimal Complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program that you might find helpful. Note how it iterates over the `DictReader` object and filters lines according to whether the Details field starts with IP.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

with open("input.csv") as input_file:
    with open("output.csv", "w") as output_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            if not row["Details"].startswith("IP"):
               writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to parse the contents of your CSV File.

One of the example snippets in the official docs is

```python
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

From that, all you have to do really is do some string manipulation on `row` rather than just calling `print()` on it. If you need help with that, again [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) should prove useful